# Errors when changing user

Tags: bash, arch-linux, zsh, login, su

Every time I use `su myName` to change my user, I always get these 3 errors.

```bash
-bash: zstyle: command not found
-bash: autoload: command not found
-bash: compinit: command not found
```

It only happens when switching to a normal user.
How do I get rid of it?

System:

- Arch x86_64
- Terminal: Bash (tried to use zsh before but then removed it)

**Edit:**
The same error also happens when just executing `bash` in the console

Comment: Those are associated with zsh, so I would assume you've gotten some zsh configuration into a configuration file bash (also) uses. Unfortunately I can't remember what those are (I've used zsh for ages), but grep for zstyle/autoload/compinit in the dotfiles of the user you see that when changing to.

Answer (score 1):

As indicated by the *-bash* starting each lines of the ouput, `su` has tried to launch a *login* shell (1).

That is to say that /etc/profile, myName_Home_Dir/.bash_profile, myName_Home_Dir/.bash_login, and  myName_Home_Dir/.profile,  will be read and commands found in them executed.

So we can presume that `zstyle`, `autoload` and `compinit` are commands that have been left over inadvertently in one of the above files, most probably /etc/profile or myName_Home_Dir/.profile if previously using another shell.

---

(1) As pointed out by [Gilles](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/885/gilles-so-stop-being-evil) in following comments, this should not have been the case, had you actually `su myName` as you stated since `su myName` should have only launched an *interactive* shell (not reading instructions in the `/etc/profile` and `myName_$HOME/.profile`). Therefore, you almost probably asked for `su - myName`, synonymous of `su --login myName` explicitly triggering a login shell.

Comment: Thank you ^^ it was automatically installed with zsh and I forgot to delete the content

Comment: Actually `su myName` does not run a login shell, so it would load `~/.bashrc` (and `/etc/bash.bashrc` or similar on some systems) but none of the `*profile*` files you list. But from the output given in the question, the asker is actually running `su - myName` or similar (`-bash` indicates a login shell). @Phill Be precise when asking for help!

Comment: @Phill Zsh does not read any of the same profile files as bash, and installing zsh would not touch any of the files that bash reads. Zsh has its own files (`.zshrc`, `.zprofile`, etc.). That can only have been done manually (and it was a mistake).

Comment: Thanks @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' for that additional deduction I had actually missed. I'll add it as part of the above answer.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' I renamed my .bashrc and .bash_profile since I followed the docs